# What language does Worf speak on a daily basis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, languages, worf

Worf obviously knows Klingon as he has been seen translating Klingon phrases for his Federation colleagues.

> **Gowron:** We shall see. (in Klingon) CHEGH-chew jaj-VAM jaj-KAK!
>
> **Worf:** He said, "Today is a good day to die."
>
> <sub>[DS9: The Way of the Warrior](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/474.txt)</sub>

But having been mostly raised by humans, he would be proficient in English as well (or Russian possibly... but an Earth language nonetheless).

So, what language does Worf regularly use throughout the shows? Does he speak Klingon and let the Universal Translators do their job or does he speak English, switching it up while in Klingon company?

**Why this question is interesting:**

Klingons tend to look down on Worf for "abandoning" his Klingon heritage in favor of Federation ideals. Despite his efforts to be as Klingon as possible, he's still an outcast among his people. If Klingon isn't his native language and he speaks it with an accent or speaks in English instead, it gives Klingons another reason to think of Worf as an outsider no matter how many times he proves his honor in other ways.

**EDIT:**

I'm aware of the inconsistencies in the way the universal translators decide to translate, especially when dealing with the Klingon language (which is what makes this question so hard for me to figure out on my own). What I'm looking for is something in the dialogue or some other sort of reference that indicates what language he's using. Perhaps a Klingon who pokes fun at Worf's accent/improper use of the Klingon language or looking down on him for spending most of his time speaking like a human. Something like that.

Comment: Words come later. It is the scent that first speaks of Worf.

Comment: Since he has to translate Klingon for everyone, despite them all having translators, why do you think he could be speaking Klingon and letting the translator handle it?

Comment: @Axelord - Because Klingons in general are translated well. Only a handful of phrases go untranslated.

Comment: In a surprise to everyone, Esperanto.  Worf plays by his own rules.

Answer (score 5):

(From my comment on my previous answer) It would be impossible to tell. It is believed that the Universal Translator can fit in a Starfleet officer’s Combadge. If this is true, then unless you find Worf tapping it (or somehow interacting with it), when actually speaking Klingon (sometimes he speaks Klingon and we hear it), Worf may be capable of speaking English without a Universal Translator. Also, you made a mistake because when he speaks to Klingons, he often speaks in Klingon and English. Also, Worf lost his parents in 2346 (when he was 6 years old) when the Romulans attacked the Khitomer colony. Worf grew up in a Klingon society for six years of his childhood until he became part of a human society (in which he got his foster parents). However, Worf is still a native Klingon and I would expect that he would be capable of speaking Klingon, just as he is capable following all the traditions and customs of Klingons.

However, in season 1, episode 19 (Heart of Glory), three Klingon fugitives come aboard the Enterprise, they speak to Worf about how for a Klingon to serve on a human Starfleet vessel. Worf tells the computer “*O’mat gri t’m pffiots*” (a type of Klingon food), with no noticeable objection from the Konmel and Korris. **This makes me believe that Worf speaks Klingon and English both fluently. Notice that whenever a Klingon ship is seen and its crew communicates to the Enterprise’s bridge they always speak in English, because they are capable of it; in season 2, episode 8 (“A Matter of Honor”), Riker comes aboard a Klingon vessel as a participant of the “Officer Exchange Program”. At some point when Riker takes the oath to obey Captain Kargan’s orders, Lieutenant Klag objects and tells Kargan that Riker is lying in Klingon; Captain Kargan tells Lieutenant Klag also in Klingon to “Speak in their language!” I am not sure why the Klingon fugitives aboard the Enterprise in “Heart of Glory” do not prefer to speak Klingon with Worf. [This post may be an explanation as to why the Klingons prefer to speak to Worf in English](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/25152/in-star-trek-why-do-klingons-speak-english-to-other-klingons), however it still comes back to the idea that they are using a Universal Translator. I could not find any episode in which a Klingon accuses Worf of not being able to speak Klingon well.** Konmel specifically says, “Tell me, what is it like for the hunter to lie down with the prey”. Korris says, “Does it make you gentle”. The fugitives believe that Worf is like them, that humans have been forcing him to act with kindness. Worf says, “Yes... yes, those feelings are still a part of me. But I control them. They do not rule me” At about the end of the episode, Korris says to Worf, “You are a sham. My words were dust upon the ground. Your blood has no fire. You are weak like them. **I don’t care what you look like—you are no Klingon!**” Worf is found as an outcast in other perspectives from Klingons, but I believe not because of the way he speaks.

Comment: You're right that it would be impossible to tell solely based on the language used during filming. But it's entirely possible that there's dialogue somewhere in which he's accused by other Klingons of having a poor grasp on the language or being made fun of for spending so much time speaking like a human. I know the universal translators are completely inconsistent throughout the shows so I'm not asking that his native language be derived from the language we've heard on screen; I'm asking for dialogue or other references that indicate what language he uses.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I would appreciate if you reviewed it @TheIronCheek

Comment: I'm not sure what you're answer is. Is it just that "it would be impossible to tell"? The rest of your answer seems to argue that he knew both Klingon and English, a point that was already stated in my question. There's not much in your answer that. Sometimes Klingon words get translated to English by the translators, sometimes they don't. There doesn't seem to be much rhyme or reason to it other than narrative reasoning so I don't think your examples can be used to determine with any certainty what language is normally spoken.

Comment: Nobody can say with certainty that they know what the answer to this question is. I believe that Worf speaks both English and Klingon because I have found no evidence that any Klingon has shown an opposition to the way Worf speaks, meaning that I believe that it is not the way he speaks that makes him an outcast. The Klingons that I spoke about in “Heart of Glory” maybe spoke to Worf in English because they speak to any member of Starfleet that way, I cannot be certain.

Comment: I do not believe there is a need for a Universal Translator for Worf. After all he served as a Lieutenant on Enterprise-D and then as a Lieutenant Commander on Defiant. I believe that a Starfleet member of his rank should be capable of speaking fluent English - he went to Starfleet Academy and was successful. I see no reason why Worf shouldn’t be capable of speaking English. @TheIronCheek

Comment: I'm not arguing that he isn't capable of speaking in English. I'm just not convinced that he normally chooses to speak in English because of the way the universal translators work.

Comment: I just couldn’t find any evidence that suggests either of the two possibilities: “Does he speak Klingon and let the Universal Translators do their job or does he speak English, switching it up while in Klingon company?” @TheIronCheek

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. Your answer just isn't very clear that that's the point you're making.

Comment: I guess that if we assume that Worf only has a Universal Translator in his Combadge on his uniform, then that means he isn’t wearing his Combadge with his Universal Translator in “The Emissary” (Season 2, Episode 20) in TNG, when Worf and K’Ehleyr dress up in Klingon uniforms in their attempt to use guile to trick the *T’Ong* crew into believing that Worf is the Captain of the Enterprise, which is supposedly under Klingon rule, to inform the *T’Ong* that the war between the Federation and Klingons was over long ago. @TheIronCheek

Comment: Continuation to last comment: Worf speaks English in this scene, and if he isn’t wearing his Combadge, assuming what I said previously is true, then that means he isn’t carrying a Universal Translator but is still able to speak English. @TheIronCheek

Comment: @Guy We can't be 100% sure he isn't using a UT in these circumstances. While the UT is traditionally explained as being in the commbadge, we have seen implanted UT's before (DS9 Little Green Men). It's also entirely possible to hide a commbadge under Klingon Armor.

Comment: That is possible! We cannot be sure @ench